# setTitleImage and FileLocator

Tags: java, eclipse

I am going to set title Image of jface dialog in the java plugin. When I write the below code, I have an error. The file cannot be found. What should I do?

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("Layout");
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icon/c.png"), null);
image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), url.toString());
setTitleImage(image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL returned by `FileLocator.find` uses a special 'protocol' value which is only understood by Eclipse and JFace code (something like `bundleentry://84.fwk537066525/icon/c.png`). SWT code such as `Image` does not understand the URL.

The best thing to do is create the `Image` from a JFace `ImageDescriptor`:

```
ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);

Image image = desc.createImage();
```

You can also use `FileLocator.toFileURL` but this may cause the plugin to be unpacked so should be avoided in this case where there is a better alternative.